# Make boxes (box plots) continuous in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there an option to draw all such boxes combined in one continous hose?
What I mean is a connected line across all maximums, and minimums and medians and the mean but finally looking like one boxplot. I know I can plot them all as lines but that does not make them look like a boxplot.

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Calculate stats and use `geom_ribbon`

Comment: with stats you mean median, iqr, max, min and mean? As far as I can see geom_ribbon supports "only" three values whereas a boxplot provides five?

Comment: I guess you can plot ribbon and geom_smooth (for min, max) together .

Comment: doesn't geom_smooth represent a function applied across the data?

Comment: I mean when you have geom_smooth in your plot right now and it probably represents mean you can make another geom_smooth for min or max

Comment: I got the idea in principle but geom_smooth requires something like "lm", "glm", "loess" and so on. Or not?
At the moment I have a geom_ribbon for median and +/-iqr. Now I can add two geom_line for min and max. I guess this is what you think of the geom_smooth, I just do not understand how to apply.

Comment: This is what you'll need to find yourself. I guess that `method = "loess"` might work

Comment: no, I cannot provide loess my min or max values. But geom_line is working. Just have to tune the visualization properties now :) Thanks so far!

Comment: Please add an answer yourself once you've found the solution so that the question no longer appears unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @PoGibas I think what you are looking for is:

```
p <- ggplot(data = ...) + geom_boxplot(...)  # code for your boxplot goes here 
p2 <- ggplot_build(p)
p3 <- p2$data[[1]]

p +  
  geom_ribbon(data = p3,  
              aes(x = x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), 
               fill = "red", alpha = .5) # or your favorite color/alpha combo
```

Please post a minimum reproducible example with data next time. See the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) package for help with that.